# android 2.3.3 fixed footer issue

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile

I have a jquery mobile page in which I have a textbox. On clicking on the textbox the the virtual keyboard appears on the phone screen.

The problem starts here. If I run the page in android 2.3.3, the footer on my page comes up as the keyboard appears. But this does not happen when i run my page on ICS. I know there is bug in android 2.3.3 related to fixed positioning of header amd footer([github link](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/3695)).

Is this problem beacuse of the same reason?

Please Help !! Thanks !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Make sure to disable zooming in your app by adding this meta - tag to your head:

   `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`
2. Create your page with a footer as you would normally. Make sure NOT TO ADD `data-position="fixed"`
3. Instead, add a class "fixedFooter" to the class attribute of the footer: `class="fixedFooter"`
4. Create the class "fixedFooter" in your CSS(-file):

   ```
   .fixedFooter 
   {
      position: fixed !important;
      left: 0px !important;
      right: 0px !important;
      bottom: 0px !important;
      z-index: 999 !important;
   }
   ```

Comment: first step lack :   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

Answer (score 1):

If your code works on ICS and doesn't work in Android 2.3.x this is because 2.3.x bug in `style="position:fixed;"`

In your HTML head change meta to this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,
     minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
```

This solves Android 2.3.x issues.

More info:
http://benfrain.com/easy-css-fix-fixed-positioning-android-2-2-2-3/
http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/

Edit:
I don't recommend to change viewport for all devices. It can cause different behaviours like user can't make zoom, pinch etc. One should detect whether visitor uses a Gingerbread device and change viewport if user has Gingerbread. To check Android version you can use this:
[Detecting Android Browser (from v. 1 to 2.3 firmware) in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14021976/detecting-android-browser-from-v-1-to-2-3-firmware-in-php/22362968#22362968)

Answer (score 0):

remove the  "user-scalable=no" from the viewport and all works wel

explained @ http://wil.to/android-positioning/

worked like a charm on 2.2.2