# Detecting Android Browser (from v. 1 to 2.3 firmware) in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, browser-detection

I need to detect if the browser is Android (only from 1 to version 2.3), would this work?

```
if(preg_match('/Android [1-2.3]/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
 echo 'something';
}
```

Comment: No. The regex engine can't know how ranges of version numbers work, can it? Also you are misusing the character class, even if it was just a range of numbers you are trying to match. This will match `Android 1`, `Android 2`, `Android .` and `Android 3`. In fact it will match if any of these is a substring of the input (so it would also match `Android 2.5`). Could you show us the actual possible version numbers that could show up in the input?

Comment: Well, I need to echo a fallback for android versions that don't support SVG (so all the versions < 2.3).

Comment: That doesn't really help here. A list of "bad" version numbers would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Regex can match exactly `Android [1-2.3]` .

`Android ([1](?:\.[0-9])?|[2](?:\.[0-3])?$)`

For `MSIE [6-8] Android [1-2.3]`

`MSIE [6-8] Android ([1](?:\.[0-9])?|[2](?:\.[0-3])?)$`

[Running regex here](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?337qg)

Comment: Will also match `Android 2.4`

Comment: What about this?
/Android [12]\.\d/

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno that will also match any version `2.*`

Comment: Thanks! :)
Last question, how can I "integrate" this regex with /MSIE [6-8]/? It should be something like if(preg_match('/MSIE [6-8]|Android [1](?:\.[0-9])?|Android [2](?:\.[0-3])?$/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
Correct? :)

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno it will be like `MSIE [6-8](Android [1](?:\.[0-9])?|Android [2](?:\.[0-3])?$)` adjust the spaces in between.

Comment: MSIE [6-8]Android ([1](?:\.[0-9])?|[2](?:\.[0-3])?)$ this will be good, @MultiformeIngegno because the part outside is static not changing.

Comment: Uhm.. doesn't seem to match IE :(

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno it's working well, see running regex here http://regexr.com?337tj .

Answer (score 0):

I don't know really know what the UserAgents for those devices look like, but the pattern you have is not likely to be what you want. I suspect you want something more along the lines of:

```
'/Android (1\.\d|2\.[012])/'
```

There are lots of different ways you could write the pattern, but essentially this one says that `Android` needs to be followed by either `1.{any number}` or `2.0, 2.1 or 2.2`

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you use Browscap for browser detection.

`get_browser` function doc http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

'Actual' browscap .ini file downloads [http://tempdownloads.browserscap.com](http://tempdownloads.browserscap.com/)

It should be noted that the project is closed at the moment and further update of browser-database in question.

Usage exapmle in your case:

```
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
if (array_key_exists('Platform', $browser) && array_key_exists('Platform_Version', $browser) && $browser['Platform'] == 'Android' && $browser['Platform_Version'] <= 2.3) {
    echo 'Android <2.3 version';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex to get the Android browser version, be it in x.x.x format or x.x.  I have a regex to determine if the device is using one of the versions I'm supporting (2.3.x +):

```
/Android ([2].?[3-9].?[0-9]?|[3].?[0-9].?[0-9]?|[4].?[0-9].?[0-9]?)/
```

Answer (score 0):

From github I found this code very useful: https://gist.github.com/Abban/3939726

```
if(is_old_android('2.3')) {
  echo 'This device has Android 2.3 or lower';
}

function is_old_android($version = '4.0.0'){
   if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Android')){

     preg_match('/Android (\d+(?:\.\d+)+)[;)]/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $matches);

     // $matches[0]= Android 4.1.2;
     // $matches[1]= 4.1.2

        return version_compare($matches[1], $version, '<=');
    }
}
```

Very useful function: [version_compare](http://php.net/version_compare)